# Node.js Docker containers with unique environment variables for each user ID

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, environment-variables, containers

I'm working on a Node.js application that processes requests for multiple users. I have a `.env` file that contains an array of user IDs, and I want to run separate Docker containers for each user ID with unique environment variables for each container.

Here's an example of my `.env` file:

CONNECTIONS=1

USER_IDS=["1","2","3"]

INTERVAL=4000

I'm using Docker Compose to manage my containers, and I want to ensure that each container has a different value for the `USER_ID` environment variable, based on the user IDs specified in the `.env` file.

I've tried using the `--scale` option with Docker Compose, but it seems to set the same value for `USER_ID` in all containers.

How can I set the environment variables dynamically for each container based on the user IDs in the `.env` file, so that each container has a different `USER_ID` value?

Any help or guidance on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: This approach won't scale to any non-trivial number of users.  (If you have 1,000 users, do you plan to run 1,000 separate containers?)  You can specify a Compose `environment:` when you start the container, but you'd have to explicitly write out a separate Compose service entry for each instance and set the environment variable.  Why can't you run just one instance of the application?

Comment: I want to write a separate node js script which will run the activity for each room and the script should be run parallel for all the rooms not sequentially.
How can I achieve this goal there is any way to doing this and they use npm autocannon library for check load testing of the application